# Strategy not executing on Open, High, Low, Close as it should with calc_on_order_fills = true and calc_on_every_tick = true

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am trying to figure out the pine script execution model and seem to not understand how it works. From what I read, if I set the calc_on_every_tick and calc_on_order_fills to true, the Pine Script Execution Engine should calculate the script 4 times for every bar in the backtest - on open, high, low and close.

Yet - even with those parameters set to true, the engine seems to calculate the strategy only on close of the bar.

More over - even in forward  testing - it also seems to recalculate the script on every tick but "from scratch" without "remembering" the value of variable "tick_number" (tick_number  should be reset to 1.0 on every bar but not on every tick - so in "real time", forward testing after 5 ticks the variable should have value 10.0 after just 5 ticks).

The code below plots only variable "first price" with values equal to the bar close (all other prices are "na" all the time) and to my understanding of how this works - first_price, second_price, third_price and fourth_price should all be plotted with open, low, high, close values.

Would most appreciate help with this!

Thank you in advance!

```
strategy(title="Testing Strategy Execution Model", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick=true, process_orders_on_close=true, calc_on_order_fills=true, pyramiding=0, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, currency=currency.USD)

prince_input = close

var float first_price = na
var float second_price = na
var float third_price = na
var float fourth_price = na
var float fifth_price = na


buy_signal = false
exit_buy_signal = false

tick_number = 1.0

if(tick_number == 5.0)
    fifth_price := prince_input
    tick_number := 10.0
if(tick_number == 4.0)
    fourth_price := prince_input
    tick_number := 5.0
if(tick_number == 3.0)
    third_price := prince_input
    tick_number := 4.0
if(tick_number == 2.0)
    second_price := prince_input
    tick_number := 3.0

if(tick_number == 1.0)
    first_price := prince_input
    tick_number := 2.0

if(close > sma(close,50))
    buy_signal := true    
if(close < sma(close,50))
    exit_buy_signal := true

if(exit_buy_signal)
    strategy.close("Long", when = exit_buy_signal)
else if(buy_signal)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

// PLOTS
plot(first_price, title='First Price', style=plot.style_circles, color=color.red, linewidth=3)    
plot(second_price, title='Second Price', style=plot.style_circles, color=color.purple, linewidth=3)    
plot(third_price, title='Third Price', style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green, linewidth=3) 
plot(fourth_price, title='Fourth Price', style=plot.style_circles, color=color.yellow, linewidth=3) 
plot(fifth_price, title='Fifth Price', style=plot.style_circles, color=color.blue, linewidth=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the runtime works. The rollback process resets all variables on every realtime bar iteration. See: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html#calculation-based-on-realtime-bars